# Drupal Menu permissions

Tags: drupal, menu, permissions

I am in need of a Drupal module that will allow to give a certain group of users the permissions to access admin/build/menu screen, but be able to administer only a certain menu. Basically a permissions menu per roles.
I've tried a few modules, **Menu Ownership**(**also tried Menu Perms, Menu Access, Delegate Menu Admin**) even does exactly what I need, but it requires Rebuilding Permissions, which I am afraid to do because I have a **{node_access}** table with 17000rows(I know, extremely huge!).
If anyone can suggest me a good lightweight module that does permissions for menus, I would really appreciate it!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [Menu Admin per Menu](http://drupal.org/project/menu_admin_per_menu)

> By default, Drupal allows only users with "administrer menu
>   permission" to add, modify or delete menu items. In case you want for
>   instance to let certain users manage primary links or secondary links
>   but not navigation menu, this module provides this functionality

.

Comment: Sorry, but can I just confirm with you guys...does this module require rebuilding the permissions? In my tests, I didn't see this to happen. Thanks again!

Comment: @Miha Iancu I don't think you should have to do any manual calls to rebuild the menu.  If it requires it, then it should have done it automatically.  I've never had to do anything extra to make it work.

Comment: I agree, I shouldn't have to do any additional work, but unfortunately I am talking about a very big project that might crash if I do it normally(It crashes when you Flush All Cache sometimes...).